# Button in ListView to edit sqlite database entry

Tags: android, listview, button, onclicklistener

I am trying to link an edit button for each ListView entry to edit the specific entry the button is associated with. For example, for each database entry which populates one row, a button will be on the far right allowing you to edit the entry. Currently, the code works with an onItemClickListener for selecting the entire row itself but I want to link that to a button in the row, rather than the whole row having to be selected.

Here is my code for the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.project_input;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

Intent intent;
TextView projectId;
DBController controller = new DBController(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> projectList =  controller.getAllProjects();
    if(projectList.size()!=0) {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override 
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                  projectId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.projectId);
                  String valProjectId = projectId.getText().toString();                   
                  Intent  objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditProject.class);
                  objIndent.putExtra("projectId", valProjectId); 
                  startActivity(objIndent); 
              }
        }); 
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,projectList, R.layout.view_project_entry, new String[] { "projectId","projectName", "projectLocation"}, new int[] {R.id.projectId, R.id.projectName, R.id.projectLocation}); 
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public void showAddForm(View view) {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProject.class);
    startActivity(objIntent);
}
}
```

The layout xml for the button is as follows:

```
                <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_button"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_details"
            android:paddingRight=" 10dp"
            android:text="Edit" />
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a `Button` inside a row of a `ListView` clickable you need to set the `onClickListener` on the `Button` itself. Since having a `Button` on a row item is not something that comes with `Android` you will need to create your own row with a `Button`. The easiest way yo do this is by creating an .xml for your row, inflate it and get a reference to the button in the `getView()` of your `Adapter`.